# Fastest way to import nodes/edges into a NetworkX DiGraph from CSV?

Tags: python, numpy, networkx, directed-graph

I'm trying to improve the speed of my NetworkX DiGraph population from CSV. Right now I've got a straight forward csv reader and graph add situation:

```
G = DiGraph()
nodes = csv.DictReader(open(nodeFile, 'rU'), ['index', 'label', 'type'])
for row in nodes:
    G.add_node(row['index'], {'index':row['index'], 'label':row['label'], 'type':row['type']})
edges = csv.DictReader(open(edgeFile, 'rU'), ['v1', 'v2', 'weight'])
for row in edges:
    G.add_edge(row['v1'], row['v2'], row[weight'])
```

The graph data I'm dealing with can get pretty big. Like 10,000,000 nodes big. Memory isn't an issue, but simple things like importing and exporting can eat up time better spent on more important data crunching.

Does anyone have any suggestions? I've been scouring NetworkX for utility methods or techniques that can help with this. I've even stripped down my import CSV requirements to these 3 columns and removed all value checking.

Thank you in advance for any ideas.

Comment: `numpy` can read csv directly with `loadtxt` and `genfromtxt`.  But both read the file row by row, constructing a list of lists before finally creating an array.  `pandas` has a compiled csv reader that's supposed to be faster.

Comment: I'll look at pandas but using the numpy loadtxt would effectively require memory to import the entire graph, then ingest it into NetworkX. genfromtxt might do the trick but I'll have to play with it. Thanks.